# Getting the right JSON format with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, couchdb

So I'm trying to send some data in a JSON format to a CouchDB database.I'm using jQuery $ajax function for that. My code looks more or less like this:

```
var someData= { "questions_data" :
                { "1": {"username": "John", "userid": "123456", "date": "12/12/2004"},
                 "2": {"username": "Mary", "userid": "123457", "date": "22/12/2004"}}};
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: someData,
                    url: '/smth/addquestion/' + id
                    dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function( res ) {
                ...;
```

And the data gets to the database as:

```
   'questions_data[1][username]': 'John',
  'questions_data[1][userid]': '123456',
  'questions_data[1][date]': '12/12/2004'...
```

With each `'questions_data[1]...'` taking up one field of a databse document. But what I'm trying to do here is to put it all in one field - `'questions_data'` and to make the rest of the request the value of this field. Can somebody help me out here please?

Comment: Thanks for posting that, I actually found the solution there. Sorry about duplicating.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.